# How to delete a line from a text file in Windows Phone 8.1 App

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8.1

I use this code to write to txt file in my app:

```
StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
StorageFolder dataFolder = await local.CreateFolderAsync("DataFolder", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
{
    data = reader.ReadLine();      
}
```

How to delete first line from txt file??

Comment: Copy all the remaining lines.

Comment: whether it is for this single command?

Comment: Open a `StreamReader`, read all lines of the file (after the first) in, close the `StreamReader`, open a `StreamWriter`, write all the lines read (making sure you *never read* the first, or otherwise *discard* it), close the `StreamWriter`.

Comment: it will consume a lot of time if the file I have 10 thousand lines

Comment: Will it? Have you *checked* it?

Comment: I just tested it, 6ms to read 10k lines and write them to a new file, delete the original and move the new file.

Comment: You said  (making sure you never read the first, or otherwise discard it).
How?

Comment: Usually you would just do a `StreamReader.Read()` into nothing, then start the reader loop.